# Serial port permission denied for non-root user with dialout group privileges even after reboot Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: serial-port, ubuntu-18.04

I write systemd services that launch with root privileges and de-privilege themselves to a system account (called mxdaemon). These services require access to the physical serial port (`/dev/ttyS0`) on the PC. Serial port `ls -l`:

`Serial port: crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 4, 64 Jun 13 22:00 /dev/ttyS0`

When run as root, the service has no problem communicating via the serial port.
When the service is configured to de-privilege to mxdaemon, I get a permission denied error when attempting to access `/dev/ttyS0`.

mxdaemon is a member of both the `dialout` & `tty` groups:

`mxdaemon : mxdaemon dialout tty`

Even after logging out and/or rebooting the PC, I still get permission denied for ANY user besides root.

Hours of scouring the Internet suggest that everything is configured correctly.

Any help would be appreciated!

-Rob

@sawdust: Thanks for the reply! Here's the info...

`/etc/group` : `dialout:x:20:mxdaemon,mxadmin`

`/etc/gshadow` : `dialout:*::mxdaemon,mxadmin`

Thanks for the pointer @sawdust - here's what the command yielded...

`ps -o user= -o group= -p 15150`

`mxdaemon root`

So, the user is `mxdaemon` but it shows being part of the `root` group?

Comment: In the files **/etc/group** and **/etc/gshadow**, what do the lines for `dialout` look like?

Comment: Use the `ps -A` command to get the pid of your daemon.  Then get a report of its owner and group with `ps -o user= -o group= -p <pid>`

Comment: Thanks @sawdust - result is shown above. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: @sawdust - Any thoughts on the above feedback I provided?

Comment: Have you tried a sanity test: access the device as a user that is in the `dialout` group?

Comment: Have you found the solution? I have the same situation. Daemon that starts as root, changes to a user `my_user`, and cannot access serial port. The port is owned by root, group dialout. User it in the group dialout, but still get "Permission denied" when opening the serial.

Comment: only `chmod 666 /dev/ttyMYPORT` would allow the application to access the serial port.