# Access to /dev/ttyUSB0 denied for dialout group member in Kubuntu 18.04

Tags: serial-port, permission-denied, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to access an ESP32 microcontroller connected via USB to /dev/ttyUSB0 on my Kubuntu 18.04 machine, but I'm getting a permission denied error:

> SerialException: [Errno 13] could not open port /dev/ttyUSB0: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/dev/ttyUSB0'

My username is in the *dialout* group in both */etc/group* and */etc/gshadow* and I have rebooted since adding the *dialout* group membership.

```
$ sudo grep dialout /etc/group /etc/gshadow
/etc/group:dialout:x:20:steve
/etc/gshadow:dialout:*::steve
$ id -Gn steve
steve adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers libvirt libvirt-qemu libvirt-dnsmasq
$ groups steve
steve : steve adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare vboxusers libvirt libvirt-qemu libvirt-dnsmasq
```

The ownership and permissions of the /dev/ttyUSB0 file are:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Nov 17 22:34 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

So I would expect the *dialout* group membership to work.

When I change the permissions on */dev/ttyUSB0* to '666', giving world read/write access, I can access the serial port:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Nov 17 22:34 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Although usable as a solution, access should work for *dialout* group members, but, based on my experiments above, it seems that the *dialout* group membership is somehow ineffective.

This question is related to *[Serial port permission denied for non-root user with dialout group privileges even after reboot Ubuntu 18.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50858443/serial-port-permission-denied-for-non-root-user-with-dialout-group-privileges-ev)*, but with some extra points.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did, and it seems to work even after unplugging and reconnecting an Arduino.

Thinking maybe the tty device I needed was a link to another device, I gathered which tty's were added to the `dev` directory after plugging in the Arduino.

In my case, two of them: /dev/ttyprintk and /dev/ttyACM0, the second of which was root/dialout ownership we expect. I changed the first one which was root/root to also be *root*/*dialout* and things worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure how this can be right. /dev/ttyprintk should be there regardless of whether or not the arduino is connected (at least it is on my system). Is there a reason you think this worked?